# CMFCPropertyGridCtrl Multiple Selection

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

Is there a way to enable multiple selection of properties in a CMFCPropertyGridCtrl?

I want to manipulate several CMFCPropertyGridProperty together e.g. for deleting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that Make column with check box and you can select with corresponding row.
you can select multiple row also.
make row with check box also.

for(int i=1;i<= Rowcount;i++)
    {

```
    GV_ITEM Item;
    Item.mask |= (GVNI_MODIFIED);
    if (!m_Grid.SetCellType(i,CheckColumn, RUNTIME_CLASS(CGridCellCheckCenter)))
        return;
    CGridCellCheckCenter *pCellCheck = (CGridCellCheckCenter*) m_Grid.GetCell(i,CheckColumn);       
    pCellCheck->SetCheck(false);
    pCellCheck = (CGridCellCheckCenter*) m_Grid.GetCell(i,CheckColumn);         
}
```

then you check the state of row and get the value of that multiple row.
you can go through this site also if u needed http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479/Tree-control-and-Buttons-for-MFC-Grid-control

Comment: This sounds like an easier workaround, I will first try this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No! CMFCPropertyGridCtrl only allows a single selection.

I even have no idea what functionality you want to have with a multiple selection. You can only hit and change only one property. This is the same with the BCG controls.

Comment: I would like to select a lot of them and then hit "delete" to delete them.

Comment: OK. I understand your intent. But the outer PropertyGrid control only knows one selected item. There is no internal mechanism that allows to select a list. There is only one internal member m_pSel that controls one "selected item". Sorry. You may extent this by subclassing this and using m_pSel only as focused item and add handling of Ctrl+Mouseclick for multiple selections. But it will be a hard work...

Comment: Yes, that could be a work around, I just couldn't find an easy way to highlight multiple properties. I think I will go with the "check-boxes option instead"